# Partial differential of sharpe ratio of a portfolio with n ( =4 )equities with respect to the allocation for each equity.

Tags: partial-derivative, finance

Sharpe  ratio is the mean of the daily returns from the portfolio divided (minus a constant )by the standard deviation of the return from the portfolio. Daily return of the portfolio is calculated by multiplying the daily return of each equity with it's allocation (for ex - 0.6 , the sum of all these allocations is equal to 1, allocation is simply how much percentage of the portfolio is that equity) and adding them up.

I want to maximize the sharpe ratio with respect to the allocations of each equity.

Is the partial differentiation even possible?

Comment: If you have $n=4$ equities, and the share in your portfolio adds to 1, then you have to determine the weights of $3$ of the equities (the last follows as $x_4=1-x_1-x_2-x_3$). I am not sure if your problem is concave so that you can use the first order approach, but if it is, you should compute 3 first order conditions via partial differentiation, yes.